ArgoCD Only Creating the Last Key/Value Pair in Range Loop
When I execute helm template locally, it prints all Ingress custom resources as expected. However, when I deploy to ArgoCD, it's only picking up the last value in the range. See the Ingress template and values.yaml below.
ingress.yaml
{{- range $index, $record :=  .Values.dnsRecords.cnameRecords }}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cname-record-ingress-{{ $index }}
  namespace: {{ $.Values.deployment.namespace }}
  annotations:
    # Disable Cert-Manager
    cert-manager.io/issue-temporarily-disabled: "true"
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "{{ $index }}"

    # ExternalDNS Annotations for CNAME Records
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: "{{ $record.name }}"
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/record-type: "CNAME"
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/target: "{{ $record.value }}"
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: "{{ $record.ttl | default 300 }}"
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: {{ $.Release.Name }}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: dummy.com-{{ $index }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: dummy-service-{{ $index }}
                port:
                  number: 80
{{- end }}

values.yaml
dnsRecords:
  cnameRecords:
  - name: "oopizw5ap7ktcbe._domainkey.example.com"
    value: "oopizw5ap7ktcbe.dkim.amazonses.com"
  - name: "uzq4rog4echrx._domainkey.example.com"
    value: "uzq4rog4echrxx.dkim.amazonses.com"
  - name: "jqq4x6xkorwe2._domainkey.example.com"
    value: "jqq4x6xkorwe2.dkim.amazonses.com"

I expect ArgoCD to create 3 ingress resources but it's only creating the last.
